# How to resolve issues encountered when using spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I have a training data (json) based from emails and extracted using tecoholic's ner-annotator. When trying to use the below for spacy and to test if the training/machine learning worked, I keep getting the error: "Some entities could not be aligned in the text. Use 'spacy.gold.biluo_tags_from_offsets(nlp.make_doc(text), entities) to check the alignment."

I tried using the above to check the alignment but then get a different error. Here is a sample of the code that I have:

```
import json
import spacy

with open('training_data.json') as fp:
    training_data = json.load(fp)

nlp = spacy.blank('en')
nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'demo'
ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
nlp.add_pipe(ner, last = True)

for label in training_data["classes"]:
    nlp.entity.add_label(label)

optimizer = nlp.begin_training()

for text, annotations in training_data["annotations"]:
    if len(text) > 0:
        nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer)

text1 = "From: thisperson@domain.com To: thisperson@domain.com Confirmed for order 2222222"

doc = nlp(text1)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text,ent.label_)
```

ner-annotator tool link: https://github.com/tecoholic/ner-annotator

**First time using spacy**

Comment: When you get a "different error", what is it? spaCy translates annotations from your original training data to character offsets, but if those offsets don't align with spaCy's tokenizer it may be unable to use your annotations, so that could be an issue.

Comment: I was not able to capture the error, nor am I able to reproduce it again. Although, I got one right now stating that I have an attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'idx'.